# Como superponer un texto contenido dentro del sistema de columnas de Materialize

Tags: materialize, sass

Aquí detallo mi pregunta. Estoy haciendo una página web donde tengo una imagen de fondo pero al colocar un texto con el sistema de de columnas (grid) que proporciona materialize este me queda por debajo de dicha imagen de fondo y por ende no se ve. Ya intenté modificar el z-index de la imagen de fondo para que quedara por detrás del texto pero no hace ningún efecto. Cabe destacar que estoy con la versión avanzada de SAAS.

**Codígo html:**

```
<div class="row left ">
    <div class="col s12"><p>Blockchain</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row left ">
    <div class="col s12"><p>Develop, test, and deploy secure blockchain apps  </p></div>
</div>
<div class="row left">
    <div class="col s12 "><p>We develop software powered by Hyperledger</p></div>
</div>
<div class="btn-down"><img src="images/down.png"/>  
    <div class="section1"> <h3> what is a blockchain? </h3> </br> <p> dsakkljksksdasda </p> </div>
</div>
<img class="responsive-img img-header" src="images/bg.jpg">
```

**Código SAAS sin modificar (tal cual como viene):**

```
.row {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

   .col {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 $gutter-width / 2;
    min-height: 1px;
   }
}
```

Esta es la imagen de fondo:

[image: Imagen de fondo]

Y aquí pueden ver el texto que el cual se encuentra por debajo de la imagen:

[image: texto el cual quiero colocar delante de la imagen de fondo]

Mi duda es porque el z-index no funciona?. Cualquier otra propiedad que agregue si hace efecto, pero z-index no hace nada.

Comment: Estas utilizando position:absolute en la etiqueta del texto?

Comment: probé colocando position: absolute en la clase row, con esto si queda por encima, pero cuándo le coloco left para que se alinee a la izquierda quedan encima uno de otro. cabe destacar que para cada texto creo primero la fila (row) y luego  dentro de esta coloco el otro div con la clase col s12 para que ocupe todo el ancho del grid.

Comment: Debes colocar el codigo, para poder ayudarte. Asi es imposible

Comment: como hago para insertar el código de forma correcta? estoy leyendo la explicación de como dar formato pero no entiendo, soy nuevo en esto de los foros.

Comment: Debes darle a editar la pregunta, y allí en la parte superior tienes un icono que sale así { } le das allí y insertas el código.

Comment: Listo, ahora si están los códigos.

Comment: Cual es la imagen en cuestión, y cual es el texto que quieras colocar arriba de la imagen?

Comment: ya coloque la imagen de fondo, y luego movi la imagen de fondo para que se pueda apreciar el texto que queda oculto y quiero colocar delante de la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:15%; z-index:1;">
  <div class="row left ">
   <div class="col s12"><p>Blockchain</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row left ">
   <div class="col s12"><p>Develop, test, and deploy secure blockchain apps</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row left">
   <div class="col s12 "><p>We develop software powered by Hyperledger</p></div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-down"><img src="images/down.png"/>  
   <div class="section1"> <h3> what is a blockchain? </h3> </br>
    <p>dsakkljksksdasda</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma tiene que colocarse por arriba de la imagen, prueba y comentas.

Comment: Probé pero el texto se sigue ocultado detrás de la imagen. Alguna idea de porque la propiedad z-index no genera ningún efecto?

Comment: He editado, prueba!

Comment: Ahora si funciona amigo. Por que colocando la propiedad z-index directo en el HTML si funciona y en el CSS no? otra cosa... ahora como hago para que el texto sea responsivo? la imagen de fondo se va haciendo pequeña pero el texto no se va adaptando cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana y no va quedando en la misma posición en la que está originalmente.

Comment: Es que en el css que pusiste, en ninguna parte estaba el z-index. Ademas el z-index va en el div que contiene a todo el texto. Y para lo del responsive del texto puedes revisar el sistema de grillas, y que depende del tamaño vaya cambiando la clase col